# Save the file explorer panel in vim session

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, netrw

When I have *netrw* and some files open in *vim*, only the file panels are displayed when I restore the session using `.mksession`.

Is it possible to restore the `netrw` file browser panel from a saved session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A saved Vim session contains the list of open buffers, window layout, and changed options. The *netrw* plugin (like many others) uses *scratch buffers* to display its user interface in a Vim window. These contents are not persisted, but instead generated and updated by the plugin. There's no mechanism for Vim to recognize these and ask the plugin to restore on session load. Vim just sees that the netrw buffer isn't persisted on disk (i.e. `:set buftype=nofile`), and then skips it.

Some plugins like [session.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) have functionality to handle special buffers; I don't think it can restore *netrw* buffers, though.

What you *could* easily do is hooking into the `SessionLoadPost` autocmd event, and reopen *netrw* then.